# How to swap the x-labels in a boxplot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, boxplot, google-colaboratory

I have graph with several boxplot with questions identifiers on the x-axis (e.g A1, A2, A3). I like to replace the identifiers with custom text.

This doesn't do anything

```
plt.xticks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9,10],['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9','A10'])
```

This doesn't do anything

```
plt.xticks(['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9','A10'],['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9','A10'])
```

This doesn't do anything

```
plt.xticks([],[])
```

My code that I have

```
whiskerprops = dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=4.0, color='cyan')
boxprops = dict(linewidth=4.0, color='black')
capprops = dict(linewidth=4.0, color='red')
medianprops = dict(linewidth=4.0, color='black')


plt.text(2,7,"test")
plt.xticks([])
plt.tick_params(
    axis='x',
    which='both',
    bottom=False,
    labelbottom='off'  #works to hide the labels 
    )


flierprops = dict(marker='o', markersize=12, linestyle='none', markeredgecolor='green', markerfacecolor='red')
boxplot = alert_df.boxplot(column=['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9','A10'],  # these are the question IDs I like to replace

                           figsize=(15,5),
                           fontsize=15,
                           patch_artist=True, 
                           notch=True, 
                           whiskerprops=whiskerprops, 
                           boxprops=boxprops,
                           capprops = capprops,
                           medianprops=medianprops,
                           flierprops = flierprops,
                           rot=35,
                           )
```

What I like is that is a replacement:

- A1 -> "This is question 1"
- A2 -> "This is question 2"
- etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ax.set_xticklabels` is what you are looking for

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(15,5))
df.boxplot(ax=ax)
ax.set_xticklabels([f'Q{i}' for i in range(1,11)]);
```